# Matlab - set specific color for value in pcolor

Tags: matlab, colors, overlay

I've created a pcolor whose caxis ranges from -3 to 3.  However, within the data I've got lots of points whose value are exactly 1000.  What I'd like to do is keep the colouring the same for all the other points, but set the colour for any point whose value is 1000 to black.  Does anyone have any ideas how I could do this..?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Adam

--EDIT--

I am currently creating the plot using a mapping tool for pcolor, m_pcolor, as follows (see [here](http://www.eos.ubc.ca/~rich/private/mapug.html) for details):

```
m_proj('Robinson')
h = m_pcolor(Lon', Lat', input_matrix);
m_coast('Color', 'k', 'LineWidth', 1);
set(h,'EdgeColor','none');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If black as the color for values that equal 1000 is not a strict requirement, you can simply set these values to `NaN` by

```
a(a==1000) = nan;
```

The function `pcolor` will draw the `nan` values in **white**.

**~edit~**
To display the `nan` values in black, you might change the background of the axis to black:

```
set(gca, 'color', [0 0 0]);
hold on; 
pcolor(a);
```

**~edit2~**
If you cannot change the background, try the following work around:

```
h1 = pcolor(ones(size(a))); 
hold on; 
set(h1, 'facecolor', [0 0 0]); 
pcolor(a);
```

This draws two surfaces above each other with the lower one set to black.

Comment: yeah - I could definitely reassign them to nan, but the points will need to be in black.  is there a way to get pcolor to draw these points in black, not white?

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I'm afraid..  would also be problematic, as I am using a transparency mask which needs to show white.  How does matlab set the color nan takes?  does it just set it to the minimum color value available in the caxis..?

Comment: It works for me. As far as I know, nan values are not drawn at all, i.e., the place for the nan-value stays empty. Therefore the trick with the black background...

Comment: edit: make sure that you either use `hold on` if you set the background color before you use pcolor, or set the background color after you use pcolor

Comment: see my reply to mars.  keeping the NaNs transparent but changing the background to black won't work, as I am already using a transparency mask on parts of the image to show up the white behind

Comment: done.  I've left out how I create the transparency mask, as I think this isn't too relevant (other than meaning we can't use transparency here).

Answer (score 1):

As H.Muster wrote, you can set the values equal to 1000 to NaN. In this case the axis color shows through, which is white by default. If you want it to be black, you can set the 'Color' property of the axis object:

```
a=[1 2 4; 3 NaN 5; 6 7 8];
pcolor(a);
set(gca, 'Color', 'Black')
```

Comment: I think the reason this doesn't work is because I am using m_pcolor, an adjusted form of pcolor designed for plotting maps, etc.  However, this won't work well for me anyway, as I am already using a transparency mask on other parts of the image to show up white..